# How to create a grouped bar chart with plotly using an existing dataframe

Tags: python, data-visualization, plotly-python

I currently have an existing dataframe with country, mode of arrival and arrival count. I am hoping to create a grouped bar chart but I only know how to create regular bar charts.

This is the formula I am using for now

```
trace3 = go.Bar(x=df5['cor'],y=df5['arv_count'], name = 'Total arrival count by country in 2013')
iplot([trace3])
```

This is how the graph looks like:

[image]

Comment: can you please the groups of your dataframe

Comment: I want to group it by mode of arrival. By air, land,sea. @AnkushRasgon

Answer (score 2):

I hope this answers your question.Pandas will show grouped bars by columns. Entries in each row but different columns will constitute a group in the resulting plot. Therefore, you need to do something like,

```
df5.pivot("cor", "arrival", "arv_count").plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Comment: An error message of "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" shows up @Shafiqa Iqbal

Comment: You must have index with multiple duplicate values. try this
df5.reset_index().pivot("cor", "arrival", "arv_count").plot(kind='bar')